# Can you rebase a pushed branch if no one is downstream on the remote?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

There is no one downstream, but I'm more worried about git ending up in a confused state. For example if remote has 10 commits and my squashed local version has 3 I'm afraid it'll tell me I'm 7 commits behind or something and I end up having to reset. When I force push, does it just replace remote with local? Also...what exactly happens if there IS someone downstream, does all their work become a detached head?

(I use Atlassian Sourcetree btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rebase and force push no problem.  Your branches will be diverged before you push, but that's the point of what you are doing.

If there are any downstream users they will need to follow the "RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE" procedure document in the `git rebase` help page.

[Git Rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)